# Github-cli codespace ssh ubuntu@localhost: permission denied (publickey,password)

Tags: git, ssh, cs50, github-cli, github-codespaces

I wanted to connect to my Codespace through terminal using gh or github-cli. But when I try to connect to my codespace I encounter this error.

`[xyz@xyzPC  ~]$ gh cs ssh ? Choose codespace: code50/93048025 (main): ideal disco ubuntu@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password). shell closed: exit status 255`
If anyone would tell me what am I doing worng.

I tried setting the,
sshd_config  PasswordAuthentication No to Yes
Deleting .ssh and reinstalling
Tried in other linux systems.

Comment: Since you haven't mentioned it, have you tried generating a new SSH key and adding the public key to your Gitub profile?

Comment: Yes I tried it but still the same issue.